# Run jar as a webapp on Azure

Tags: java, azure, jar, azure-web-app-service

I was able to run metabase.jar on my machine (W10), and now I need to try on Azure, because it's where I have SQL Server.

Metabase.jar: [metabase.com/start/](http://www.metabase.com/start/)

I couldn't do it by myself (closure and jetty are new to me).

On Azure, I tried:

- Create a web app;
- Set to Java 8 and Jetty 9.1;
- Failed to run metabase.jar.

Comment: How far did you get? That is, did you actually deploy a web app with `metabase.jar`? Have you gone into your web app via kudu (`yourapp.scm.azurewebsites.net`) and verified it was uploaded? Did you modify the port (which defaults to 3000)? Please edit your question with more info. Otherwise, not much anyone will be able to do to help.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, @peter-pan-msft did the whole process and didn't succeed as well. I will try a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to deploy the `metabase.jar` file as a web application on Azure WebApps like on local. Then I followed the [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/12/28/running-java-jar-file-to-serve-web-requests-on-azure-app-service-web-apps/) to upload the `metabase.jar` file into the directory `wwwroot/bin` which I created it via Kudu console and create & configure a `wwwroot/web.config` below to start up the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="%ProgramW6432%\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dport.http=3000 -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\bin\metabase.jar&quot;" stdoutLogEnabled="true" startupRetryCount='10'>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The result of deployment is that I can't startup it completely without any error. It seems that the app constantly restart by Azure WebApp because of some reasons, such as some resource exceeded quotes not enough memory or unable to connect to Metabase DB. While I scaled up the tier for my testing webapp from small to large, the issue still occured. Please see the figures below.

[image]

[image]

So I think that it seems to deploy metabase on Azure only via using Docker or Virtual Machine. Hope it helps.