# Azure without spring

Tags: java, azure

I would like to deploy my ([Minimal-J](http://minimal-j.org)) web application to the azure cloud. But it's not a servlet nor a spring-boot application. The application uses an internal web server called 'nanohttpd' and is started with a main method.

Can I deploy this without 'springify' the application to the azure cloud?

Comment: You can probably host that on a VM, right?

Comment: Is that the way to go? Make a docker image from my application? I hoped for a 'lighter' solution.

Comment: possible to deploy as azure function ??

Comment: May be a possibility. But I have quite a little bit of session state. Functions should be stateless, no?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Java Web Application embedded a special web server [`nanohttpd`](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) to handle HTTP requests, but not like servlets serve in Java Web Container. So I think you can package it as a Runnable Jar file to start with a main method via command `java -jar <your jar file name>.jar`. If yes, you can create a Azure WebApp and follow my answers for these similar SO threads below to configure the `web.config` file of your web app to start a runnable jar file.

1. [Deploying Springboot to Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103878/deploying-springboot-to-azure-app-service/39444340#39444340)
2. [Run jar as a webapp on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840466/run-jar-as-a-webapp-on-azure/38847297#38847297)
3. [Azure uploaded jar but doesn't run it (Spring boot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732486/azure-uploaded-jar-but-doesnt-run-it-spring-boot/53736947#53736947)

Here is a sample configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\<your runnable jar file name>.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Per my experience, it's a simple and light solution for your current scenario.